# Cleaner way to fill in gaps in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

(This is my first time posting code so I may have done it wrong.)

I have a list of data that was collected and reported in 5 year increments for a couple of decades; then the gap was three years until more recently it was annual. I wish to fill the five- and three-year gaps with the intervening average values. List Interpolation gives me a function but it seems there should be a simpler way. Here is the list

```
{{"Australia", "AUS", 1990, 13.131}, {"Australia", "AUS", 1995, 
  16.871}, {"Australia", "AUS", 2000, 18.242}, {"Australia", "AUS", 
  2005, 16.681}, {"Australia", "AUS", 2010, 16.706}, {"Australia", 
  "AUS", 2013, 18.109}, {"Australia", "AUS", 2014, 
  18.697}, {"Australia", "AUS", 2015, 18.794}, {"Australia", "AUS", 
  2016, 19.146}}
```

The code below works for the five year gap (illustrated is the 1995-2000 gap) and I modify it for the three year, then glue them all together with Join. Very clunky. I am sure there is a more elegant way and appreciate any suggestions

```
soc6 = Differences[soc5[[2 ;; 3]]]/5
```

(*{0.2742}*)

```
soclist2 = 
 Drop[FoldList[Plus, 
   soc5[[2]], {soc6[[1]], soc6[[1]], soc6[[1]], soc6[[1]], 
    soc6[[1]]}], 1]
```

(*{17.1452, 17.4194, 17.6936, 17.9678, 18.242}*)

Answer (score 1):

Using `TimeSeriesResample`:

```
data = {{"Australia", "AUS", 1990, 13.131},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 1995, 16.871},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2000, 18.242},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2005, 16.681},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2010, 16.706},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2013, 18.109},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2014, 18.697},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2015, 18.794},
        {"Australia", "AUS", 2016, 19.146}};

Join[data[[1, ;; 2]], #] & /@ 
 TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[data[[All, 3 ;;]]]]["Path"]
```

Plotting without the `"Australia, "AUS"` bit:

```
ListLinePlot[
 TimeSeriesResample[TimeSeries[data[[All, 3 ;;]]], 
   ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}]["Path"]
 , Mesh -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: resampled plot]